# Javascript - Change images every month

Tags: javascript

I am sure that this has been raised many times, but I can't find a solution. I need to change an image **every month**, using javascript, and the closest thing I've found is:

**[THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/gLffJ/)**

But my code does not work, although all the images I call from my server and are located in the folder "img".

The script only shows the first image (of the HTML) but does not execute the others

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

**HTML:**

```
<img id="logo" src="http://example.com/img/Master.jpg" onload="logo(this)">
```

**Script**

```
function logo(img) {
  if (img.src.indexOf('default')==-1) return; // already changed 
  var d = new Date();
  var Today = d.getDate();
  var Month = d.getMonth();
  var src = "http://example.com/img/";

if (Month === 0 && (Today >= 1 && Today <= 29)) {
    src += "000.jpg";

} else if (Month === 1 && (Today >= 1 && Today <= 29)) {
    src += "001.jpg";

} else if (Month === 2 && (Today >= 1 && Today <= 29)) {
    src += "002.jpg";

} else if (Month === 3 && (Today >= 1 && Today <= 29)) {
    src += "003.jpg";

// code for 4
// code for 5
// code for 6 ...

} 

alert(src);
  img.src=src;
}
```

Comment: Holy wow. Just do `var src = "http://example.com/img/"+("00"+new Date().getMonth()).slice(-3)+".jpg"` instead of all that `if..else if...` nonsense.

Comment: Anyway...are you actually calling `logo(img)` anywhere? Defining a function by itself doesn't run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the demo on js-fiddle there is a default image named 'default.png' ur default image is named: 'Master.jpg'. Then in the logo-function you are testing if the current src still contains the word 'default': `if(img.src.indexOf('default')==-1) return;` ... u need to either name your default picture also from 'Master' to 'default' or you change the if condition according to your data.

**EDIT**

OK try to follow my example its almost the same as yours just i use sample pictures from placehold.it:

```js
function logo(img) {
  if (img.src.indexOf('default')==-1) return; // already changed 
  var d = new Date();
  var Today = d.getDate();
  var Month = d.getMonth();
  var src = "https://via.placeholder.com/150";


  if (Month === 0 && (Today >= 1 && Today <= 29)) {
      src += "?text=000.jpg";

  } else if (Month === 1 && (Today >= 1 && Today <= 29)) {
      src += "?text=001.jpg";

  } else if (Month === 2 && (Today >= 1 && Today <= 29)) {
      src += "?text=002.jpg";

  } else if (Month === 3 && (Today >= 1 && Today <= 29)) {
      src += "?text=003.jpg";

  // code for 4
  // code for 5
  // code for 6 ...
  } else if (Month === 9 && (Today >= 1 && Today <= 29)) {
    src += "?text=009.jpg";
  }

  alert(src);
  img.src=src;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=default.jpg" onload="logo(this)" />
```

Especially note that the initial image-src contains the word 'default'. Play around with that and then try to apply it to your use-case.

Answer (score -1):

Why not simplify it?

```
function logo(img) {
  var Month = d.getMonth();
  var src = "http://example.com/img/";

  if (Month == 0) {
    src += "000.jpg";

  } else if (Month == 1) {
    src += "001.jpg";

  } else if (Month == 2) {
    src += "002.jpg";

  } else if (Month == 3) {
    src += "003.jpg";

    // code for 4
    // code for 5
    // code for 6 ...

  }

  alert(src);
  img.src = src;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not does it work by taking away the days. I think the script has trouble finding the path of where the images are, and change of `http://example.com/img/`  for  `http://example.com/img` doesn't solve anything either for me ... :(

Comment: @Pablo_Web Is your path to `img` a `http://example.com/img/001.jpg`? If so, the first version should work

Comment: No matter what names I change in the images, something is not right. I'm following Mischa user recommendation, but it doesn't work for me either

Comment: @Pablo_Web Is the alert displaying popup window? Can you give actual path to image you're using?

Comment: Yes. The alert shows the popup window. I cannot publish the images of my client. The problem script is simplified with non-real information to expose the question.